# How to sync firebase with react functional components

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to sync my component React  with Firebase but i use a functional component i found somes answers in internet but it's seems complicated and doesn't worked for me
and i can't use this : useEffect(() => { base.syncState('/', { context: this, state: 'messages' }) });

my code  is

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import Formulaire from './component/Formulaire'
import Message from './component/Message'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import database from './Base'
import { getDatabase, ref, set,onValue } from "firebase/database";

function App() {
  const [state , setState] = useState({
    messages : {},
    pseudo : useParams().pseudo,
  })
  const addMessage = (message) =>{
    state.messages[`message-${Date.now()}`] = message
    setState({pseudo : state.pseudo ,messages : state.messages})
  }

    const msg = Object.keys(state.messages)
    const lastMessages = msg.map(key=>{
      return <Message key={key} pseudo={state.messages[key].pseudo} message = {state.messages[key].message} />
    })
  return (
    <div className="container-lg col-4 mt-5">
      <div>
        {lastMessages}
      </div>
      <Formulaire length={150} addMessage ={addMessage} pseudo={state.pseudo} />
    </div>
  )
}



export default App
```

And my firebaseApp code :

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

// TODO: Replace with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyB2CFjr32PoNdsnfvEgt_AijgE18lNKz2c",
  authDomain: "chat-app-42ed5.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "chat-app-42ed5",
  storageBucket: "chat-app-42ed5.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "880643875911",
  appId: "1:880643875911:web:9d04114b45bb40c2627d62",
  measurementId: "G-MP1VZCGRDP"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get a reference to the database service
const database = getDatabase(app);

export default database
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use my function writeUserData() in AddMessage function after submit message to send to REALTIME DATABASE not in UseEffect() and after to get message after refresh page i use onValue() as you say in UseEffect() and in the same time i update my state with setState()  ex:   if (data) {
setState({messages : data.messages , pseudo : state.pseudo})
} return

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import Formulaire from './component/Formulaire'
import Message from './component/Message'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import database from './Base'
import { ref, set,onValue } from "firebase/database";

function App() {

  const [state , setState] = useState({
    messages : {},
    pseudo : useParams().pseudo,
  })
  
  useEffect(()=>{
  const resultDb = ref(database);
  onValue(resultDb, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  if (data) {
    setState({messages : data.messages , pseudo : state.pseudo})
  } return 
})
   return resultDb
  },[])

  function writeUserData(message) {
    set(ref(database), {
      messages :message
    });
  }

  const addMessage = (message) =>{
    state.messages[`message-${Date.now()}`] = message
    setState({pseudo : state.pseudo ,messages : state.messages})
    writeUserData(state.messages)
  }

  const msg = Object.keys(state.messages)
  const lastMessages = msg.map(key=>{
    return <Message key={key} pseudo={state.messages[key].pseudo} message = {state.messages[key].message} />
    })
  return (
    <div className="container-lg col-4 mt-5">
      <div>
        {lastMessages}
      </div>
      <Formulaire length={150} addMessage ={addMessage} pseudo={state.pseudo} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

When you mount the `App` component, you can open a snapshot listener to RTDB, [see docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events). You do that in `useEffect` and also return a function from `useEffect` to destroy the listener when your component gets unmounted. It's called a "cleanup function", [see React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

It would look something like that:

```js
function App() {
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubListener = onValue(ref(rtdb_instance, '/YOUR_PATH'), (snapshot) => {
      // Probably iterate over `snapshot.val()` and store it in your state
    })

    // Return cleanup function
    return unsubListener;
 }, [])
}
```

Note that the dependency array is empty here, meaning it won't change. Hence, it will only be executed on inital mount.

Also please note that the code above is not tested, so your milage might vary.

Comment: Hello thank you for answer i found the solution it's similar of your i put the code !